# [Cocos2dx]How to set image for self-defined sprite?

Tags: android, c++, cocos2d-x

I'm using Cocos2dx 2.1.4 to develop game and want to create a self-defined sprite class. However, I don't know how to set an image for it. Somethings like `CCSprite::create("xxx.png")` or `initWithFile("xx.png")`.

How to do it? Do I need to override `initWithFile` in the self-defined sprite class?

Comment: Do you mean class inherited from CCSprite by self-defined sprite class?

Comment: Yes. I want to have a sprite that can call touch event. So, I creates it which inherited from CCSprite.

Answer (score 1):

You should override CCSprite's **create** method that you want to use and **onEnter**  **onExit** methods like:

```
MySprite* MySprite::create(const char *pszFileName)
{
    MySprite *pobSprite = new MySprite();
    if (pobSprite && pobSprite->initWithFile(pszFileName))
    {
        pobSprite->autorelease();
        return pobSprite;
    }
    CC_SAFE_DELETE(pobSprite);
    return NULL;
}

void MySprite::onEnter()
{
    // Register touch delegate
}

void MySprite::onExit()
{
    // Unregister touch delegate
}
```